# Flask: How to use an value taken from a database as an input for a function

Tags: html, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

I want to be able to generate a for loop which shows all prescriptions currently available to user with  and if the current user is a pharmacist, have a submit like button next to that line which decreases the current count of that prescription when it is clicked. Currently trying to decrease current_count when prescription_id=current_user.prescription_id which I know isnt right especially for cases with more than one prescription. Right now can display everything fine but throws error saying that 'User' object has no attribute 'prescription_id'. Could do with help. Code below.

```
main.py
@app.route('/patient_advice/<username>',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def advice(username):
    form = FillForm(request.form)
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first_or_404()
    prescription = Prescriptions.query.filter_by(username=username)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        prescriptions = Prescriptions.query.filter_by(prescription_id=current_user.prescription_id).first()
        prescriptions.prescription_current_count = prescriptions.prescription_current_count - 1
        prescriptions.fill_date = datetime.utcnow()
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Prescription removed')
        flash(prescriptions.prescription_current_count)
    return render_template('patient_advice.html', title='Patient Advice', user=user, prescription=prescription, form=form)

.html section
<table id="patient-advice">
{% for medicine in prescription %}
    {% if medicine.prescription_name and medicine.prescription_current_count > 0 %}
     <tr>
        <td id='prescriptionRow'>
            {{ medicine.prescription_current_count }}
            {% if (medicine.prescription_current_count < 2) %}
                round
            {% else %}
                rounds
            {% endif %}
        of {{ medicine.prescription_name }} <b>issued on:</b> {{ medicine.issue_date }}<br>
        {% if medicine.fill_date %}
            Last filled on: {{ medicine.fill_date }}
        {% endif %}

        {% if (current_user.user_type=="pharmacist") %}
            <form method=post>
                <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
                <p>
                    {{ form.prescriptionId(cols=50, rows=4) }}<br>
                </p>
                <p>{{ form.submit() }}</p>
            </form>
        {% endif %}
    </td>
    <td>
        {% if medicine.prescription_name and medicine.prescription_current_count > 0 %} {{ medicine.issued_doctor }}{% endif %}
    </td>
</tr>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</table>

forms.py:
class FillForm(Form):
    submit = SubmitField('Fill Prescription')

models.py:
class Prescriptions(UserMixin, db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "prescriptions"

    prescription_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    prescription_name = db.Column(db.String(200))
    prescription_count = db.Column(db.Integer)
    prescription_current_count = db.Column(db.Integer)
    issued_doctor = db.Column(db.String(200))
    issue_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    fill_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    username = db.Column(db.String(128))

    users = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=True)
    UserDetails = db.relationship('User', foreign_keys=users)

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(128), unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, index=True)
    user_type = db.Column(db.String(128))
    advice = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    last_seen = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

Solved by taking input from database as value from a hidden field in the form, changed parts below:
main.py:

```
if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
    prescriptions = Prescriptions.query.filter_by(prescription_id=request.form.get("prescid"))
    for medicine in prescriptions:
        medicine.prescription_current_count = medicine.prescription_current_count - 1
        medicine.fill_date = datetime.utcnow()
        db.session.commit()
        flash("Prescription Filled")
```

relevant html changes in form:

```
<form method=post>
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
    <input class="form-control" name="prescid" type="hidden" value={{ medicine.prescription_id }}>
    <p>{{ form.submit() }}</p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience the error you are describing is gennerally throw due to an issue with your databases configuration, so maybe give some information on how your database is structured? and maybe show some more code to give some more context.

and I couldn't help but notice this line in your HTML

```py
{% if (current_user.user_type=="pharmacist") %}
```

and see that this "current_user" is not defined anywhere, at least not in the code you are showing. In your render_template you are passing a user but the name of that variable is just "user" not "current_user".

Comment: hey, cheers, I added the databases above. The current_user is imported from flask_login, below is link to guide that explains it. https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins

Comment: @Marone289 It could look the `current_user` is pulling data from the `User` database and if that is the case then that would possibly be why you are reciving the error, as that database does not contain a column for `prescription_id`.  

A possible fix could be doing a comparison along the lines of `prescription_id=Prescriptions.prescription_id where Prescriptions.username == current_user.username`

I do not have experience with SQLalchemy (which this looks like) so this might not be possible but it is my best guess.

Comment: thanks for your input, I tried something similar to that before using the code I added at the bottom above. Using that way the "fill prescription" button only decreased the count of the first prescription ID it finds in the database, and decreases that ones current count, so doesnt work with multiple prescriptions.

Comment: @Marone289 If the ```prescriptions.prescription_current_count``` contains multiple values you might want to create a for loop, something like: 
```if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
     prescriptions = Prescriptions.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
     for i in prescriptions
         i.prescription_current_count = i.prescription_current_count - 1
         i.fill_date = datetime.utcnow()
     db.session.commit()
     flash('Prescription removed')```
But I am not knowledgable on SQLAlchemy so I am unsure if this will work in this case.

Comment: this loop seems to decrease the current count of every prescription linked to the username, instead of just the prescription that the submit button is next to

Comment: Then maybe try this method. In the form you use to decrease the current_count you can make the **value** of that button also contain your prescription_id ```<input class="form-control" name="commentid" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token(), prescription_id}}">``` as I don't know what this csrf_token function is this is the best idea I can give you